# Ansible playbook only running on the second of two servers in group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We have two servers in the group `web_servers`, and are trying to fetch logs. When we run the play as below, it is only returning files for the 2nd server.

-Inventory FILE-

```
[web_servers] 
(IP-redacted) server_name=QA dest_path=(web address-redacted) 
(same-IP-redacted) server_name=STAGING dest_path=(web address- 
redacted)
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: web_servers
  become: true
  remote_user: jackansible
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - set_fact: mydate="{{lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S')}}"
    - debug: var=mydate

    - name: Copy file from {{ server_name }} to local
      ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: /var/log/{{ item }}
        dest: /Users/jackl/Desktop/{{ mydate }}-{{ server_name }}-{{ item }}.txt
        flat: yes
      register: fetch_output
      loop:
        - syslog
        - faillog
        - dmesg
        - auth.log
        - kern.log
    - debug: var=fetch_output
```

Comment: What is `server_name`? Where is that defined? This is probably the cause of your issue, the file just gets override by the second server.

Comment: Hi, server_name is defined in the inventory file. One is QA, the other is STAGING

Comment: Add your inventory file,  you may redact the sensitive info.

Comment: [web_servers]

(IP-redacted) server_name=QA dest_path=(web address-redacted)

(same-IP-redacted) server_name=STAGING dest_path=(web address-redacted)

Comment: For a short test you could probably replace `server_name` with `ansible_hostname` or `inventory_hostname` and have a look if it is fetch up the files.

Comment: The line breaks are correct in the file. It's not letting me format it correctly in the comment.

Comment: This is because you should [edit] this in the question, comments are not meant for code. Also, what does the playbook output looks like, this should tell you if it indeed runs on one or multiple hosts.

Comment: (I take for granted `same-ip-redacted` in your inventory means you use the exact same IP twice) => This is because you use the same inventory hostname (i.e. the ip of your server in your case). ansible only sees one server and concatenates/merge all declared parameters. An easy way to have a good view of what ansible sees: `ansible-inventory -i your/inventory.ini --list`

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the IP address being the same that was causing this. We corrected the inventory file and got it to run on both.

Comment: @P.... I actually voted to close as caused by a typo when I commented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Zeitounator, we modified the inventory file to change the IP address at the beginning (which was the same for both hosts), to the unique web address for each host.

This worked perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).